# Async pipe on MatTable datasource doesn't sort, table contents update fine

Tags: angular, sorting, asynchronous, angular-material, angular2-observables

I have a MatTable that loads and refreshes correctly when the underlying data changes/adds/deletes, the only issue I'm having is that it doesn't sort when one of the headings are clicked, the little arrow icon appears but no changes. I'm using a conditional on the Observable in the html and I set the the sort in the ngOnInit(), but everything I've tried doesn't trigger any sorting. I can't find any example that does both an async pipe and matSort together, lot's of examples of either on their own. Any insight would be appreciated.

html:

```
   <mat-card-header layout="row">
      <mat-card-title style="margin-bottom: 4vh">
         <span>{{ msg }}</span>
      </mat-card-title>
   </mat-card-header>
   <mat-card-content>
      <table
      *ngIf="expenseDataSource$ | async as expenses"
      mat-table
      [dataSource]="expenses"
      matSort
      matSortDisableClear
      #expTbSort="matSort"
      class="mat-elevation-z8"
      >
      <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
         <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>
            <div class="center-header" style="width: 50%">Expense</div>
         </th>
         <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.id }}</td>
      </ng-container>
      <!-- Date Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="dateincurred">
         <th
            mat-header-cell
            *matHeaderCellDef
            mat-sort-header
            >
            <div class="center-header">Expense Date</div>
         </th>
         <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.dateincurred }}</td>
      </ng-container>
      <!-- Employee Id Column  -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="employeeid">
         <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>
            <div class="center-header">Employee</div>
         </th>
         <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.employeeid }}</td>
      </ng-container>
      <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns; sticky: true"></tr>
      <tr
      mat-row
      *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns"
      (click)="select(row)"
      ></tr>
      </table>
      <div class="padtop15">
         <mat-icon
            (click)="newExpense()"
            matTooltip="Add New Expense"
            class="addicon"
            color="primary"
            >
            control_point
         </mat-icon>
      </div>
   </mat-card-content>
</mat-card>
<mat-card *ngIf="!hideEditForm">
   <mat-card-header layout="row">
      <mat-card-title
         ><span>{{ msg }}</span></mat-card-title
         >
   </mat-card-header>
   <mat-card-content>
      <app-expense-detail
      [selectedExpense]="expense"
      [employees]="employees$ | async"
      (cancelled)="cancel('cancelled')"
      (saved)="save($event)"
      (deleted)="delete($event)"
      >
      </app-expense-detail>
   </mat-card-content>
</mat-card>
```

ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table';
import { MatSort, Sort } from '@angular/material/sort';
import { Expense } from '@app/expense/expense';
import { Employee } from '@app/employee/employee';
import { EmployeeService } from '@app/employee/employeev3.service';
import { ExpenseService } from '@app/expense/expense.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, tap, map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-expense',
  templateUrl: 'expense-home.component.html',
})
export class ExpenseHomeComponent implements OnInit {
  employees$?: Observable<Employee[]>;
  expenses: Expense[];
  expenses$?: Observable<Expense[]>;
  expenseDataSource$: Observable<MatTableDataSource<Expense>> | undefined;
  expense: Expense;
  hideEditForm: boolean;
  initialLoad: boolean;
  msg: string;
  todo: string;
  url: string;
  size: number = 0;
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['id', 'dateincurred', 'employeeid'];

  @ViewChild('expTbSort') expTbSort = new MatSort();

  constructor(
    private employeeService: EmployeeService,
    private expenseService: ExpenseService
  ) {
    this.hideEditForm = true;
    this.initialLoad = true;
    this.expenses = [];
    this.expense = {
      id: 0,
      employeeid: 0,
      categoryid: '',
      description: '',
      amount: 0.0,
      dateincurred: '',
      receipt: false,
      receiptscan: '',
    };
    this.msg = '';
    this.todo = '';
    this.url = '';
  } // constructor

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.msg = 'loading expenses from server...';
    this.expenses$ = this.expenseService.get();
    this.expenseDataSource$ = this.expenses$.pipe(
      map((expenses) => {
        const dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Expense>(expenses);
        // dataSource.data = expenses;
        dataSource.sort = this.expTbSort;
        return dataSource;
      }),
      tap(() => {
        this.employees$ = this.employeeService.get();
        if (this.initialLoad === true) {
          this.msg = 'expenses and employees loaded!';
          this.initialLoad = false;
        }
      })
    );
  }

  select(selectedExpense: Expense): void {
    this.todo = 'update';
    this.expense = selectedExpense;
    this.msg = `Expense ${selectedExpense.id} selected`;
    this.hideEditForm = !this.hideEditForm;
  } // select

  /**
   * cancelled - event handler for cancel button
   */
  cancel(msg?: string): void {
    this.hideEditForm = !this.hideEditForm;
    this.msg = 'operation cancelled';
  } // cancel

  /**
   * update - send changed update to service update local array
   */
  update(selectedExpense: Expense): void {
    this.expenseService.update(selectedExpense).subscribe({
      // Create observer object
      next: (exp: Expense) => (this.msg = `Expense ${exp.id} updated!`),
      error: (err: Error) => (this.msg = `Update failed! - ${err.message}`),
      complete: () => {
        this.hideEditForm = !this.hideEditForm;
      },
    });
  } // update

  /**
   * save - determine whether we're doing and add or an update
   */
  save(expense: Expense): void {
    expense.id ? this.update(expense) : this.add(expense);
  } // save

  /**
   * add - send expense to service, receive newid back
   */
  add(newExpense: Expense): void {
    this.msg = 'Adding expense...';
    newExpense.id = 0;
    this.expenseService.add(newExpense).subscribe({
      // Create observer object
      next: (exp: Expense) => {
        this.msg = `Expense ${exp.id} added!`;
      },
      error: (err: Error) => (this.msg = `Expense not added! - ${err.message}`),
      complete: () => {
        this.hideEditForm = !this.hideEditForm;
      },
    });
  } // add

  /**
   * newExpense - create new expense instance
   */
  newExpense(): void {
    this.expense = {
      id: 0,
      employeeid: 0,
      categoryid: '',
      description: '',
      amount: 0.0,
      dateincurred: '',
      receipt: false,
      receiptscan: '',
    };
    this.msg = 'New expense';
    this.hideEditForm = !this.hideEditForm;
  } // newExpense

  /**
   * delete - send expense id to service for deletion
   */
  delete(selectedExpense: Expense): void {
    this.expenseService.delete(selectedExpense.id).subscribe({
      // Create observer object
      next: (numOfExpensesDeleted: number) => {
        numOfExpensesDeleted === 1
          ? (this.msg = `Expense ${selectedExpense.id} deleted!`)
          : (this.msg = `Expense ${selectedExpense.id} not deleted!`);
      },
      error: (err: Error) => (this.msg = `Delete failed! - ${err.message}`),
      complete: () => {
        this.hideEditForm = !this.hideEditForm;
      },
    });
  }
} // ExpenseHomeComponent
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the sort functionality working by adding a custom sort method and added the matSortChange attribute on the table

Answer (score 0):

I've been dealing with this myself. I think the issue is your line: `dataSource.sort = this.expTbSort;` is running before the view is rendered.

The line `@ViewChild('expTbSort') expTbSort = new MatSort();` means the variable `expTbSort` is to be populated with data taken from the view, so the view must have rendered before assigning `dataSource.sort`.

The way you have implemented the async pipe ensures that the view will not render until after the ngOnInit has run and `this.expenseDataSource$` is defined.

I'm not sure of the ideal solution for your case, but hopefully this perspective has been helpful. In my case, my table is populated with the response from an API call, so I define `dataSource.sort` inside of the `.subscribe()` callback. I did not need to use the `ngAfterViewInit` lifecycle hook as in the examples in the Angular Material docs.